# Web Scraping with R on multiple pages/links

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a **list of 5000 movies** in an excel file:

1. Avatar
2. Tangled
3. Superman Returns
4. Avengers : Endgame
5. Man of Steel

**And so on....**

I need to **extract weekend collections** of these movies.
The weekend collections are available on **boxofficemojo.com** website.

By writing the following code, i am only able to fetch the Weekend collections of one single movie 'Avatar' since the url mentioned in the code contains only the details of 'Avatar'.

```
library(rvest) 

webpage <- read_html("https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl876971521/weekend/?ref_=bo_rl_tab#tabs") 

weekend_collections <- webpage %>%
                            html_nodes(".mojo-field-type-rank+ .mojo-estimatable") %>%
                            html_text()
```

Other movies will have different url's.
5000 different movie's weekend collections will be in 5000 different url's.

Is it possible to just **give the list of the movies and ask r to fetch the weekend collections of every movie** without providing the respective url's of the movies ?

I can **add the url's of the movies manually** and perform the task but it **isn't a great idea to manually add the url's** of the movies to the code.

**So how do i fetch the weekend collections of these 5000 movies ?**

I am new to R. 
Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to automate the search process on this site, since it is easy enough to generate the search string and parse the incoming html to navigate to the weekends page.

The problem is that the search will sometimes generate several hits, so you can't be sure you are getting exactly the right movie. You can only examine the title afterwards to find out.

Here is a function you can use. You supply it with a movie title and it will try to get the url to the weekend collections for the *original release*. It will select the first hit on the search page, so you have no guarantee it's the correct movie.

```
get_weekend_url <- function(movie)
{
  site            <- "https://www.boxofficemojo.com"
  search_query    <- paste0(site, "/search/?q=")
  search_xpath    <- "//a[@class = 'a-size-medium a-link-normal a-text-bold']"
  release_xpath   <- "//option[text() = 'Original Release']"
  territory_xpath <- "//option[text() = 'Domestic']"
  weekend         <- "weekend/?ref_=bo_rl_tab#tabs"
  movie_url       <- url_escape(movie)                 %>%
                     {gsub("%20", "+", .)}             %>%
                     {paste0(search_query, .)}         %>%
                     read_html()                       %>%
                     html_nodes(xpath = search_xpath)  %>%
                     html_attr("href")

  if(!is.na(movie_url[1]))
  {
   release      <- read_html(paste0(site, movie_url[1]))   %>%
                   html_node(xpath = release_xpath)        %>%
                   html_attr("value")                      %>%
                   {paste0(site, .)}

  } else release <- NA  # We can stop if there is no original release found

  if(!is.na(release))
  {
    target <- read_html(release)                 %>%
              html_node(xpath = territory_xpath) %>%
              html_attr("value")                 %>%
              {paste0(site, ., weekend)}

  } else target <- "Movie not found"
  return(target)
}
```

Now you can use `sapply` to get the urls you want:

```
movies <- c("Avatar",
            "Tangled",
            "Superman Returns",
            "Avengers : Endgame",
            "Man of Steel")

urls <- sapply(movies, get_weekend_url)
urls
#>                                                                            Avatar 
#>  "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl876971521/weekend/?ref_=bo_rl_tab#tabs" 
#>                                                                           Tangled 
#>  "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl980256257/weekend/?ref_=bo_rl_tab#tabs" 
#>                                                                  Superman Returns 
#> "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl4067591681/weekend/?ref_=bo_rl_tab#tabs" 
#>                                                                Avengers : Endgame 
#> "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl3059975681/weekend/?ref_=bo_rl_tab#tabs" 
#>                                                                      Man of Steel 
#> "https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl4034037249/weekend/?ref_=bo_rl_tab#tabs"
```

Now you can use these to get the tables for each movie:

```r
css  <- ".mojo-field-type-rank+ .mojo-estimatable"
weekends  <- lapply(urls, function(x) read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(css) %>% html_text)
```

Which gives you:

```r
weekends
#> $`Avatar`
#>  [1] "Weekend\n            " "$77,025,481"           "$75,617,183"          
#>  [4] "$68,490,688"           "$50,306,217"           "$42,785,612"          
#>  [7] "$54,401,446"           "$34,944,081"           "$31,280,029"          
#> [10] "$22,850,881"           "$23,611,625"           "$28,782,849"          
#> [13] "$16,240,857"           "$13,655,274"           "$8,118,102"           
#> [16] "$6,526,421"            "$4,027,005"            "$2,047,475"           
#> [19] "$980,239"              "$1,145,503"            "$844,651"             
#> [22] "$1,002,814"            "$920,204"              "$633,124"             
#> [25] "$425,085"              "$335,174"              "$188,505"             
#> [28] "$120,080"              "$144,241"              "$76,692"              
#> [31] "$64,767"               "$45,181"               "$44,572"              
#> [34] "$28,729"               "$35,706"               "$36,971"              
#> [37] "$15,615"               "$16,817"               "$13,028"              
#> [40] "$10,511"              
#> 
#> $Tangled
#>  [1] "Weekend\n            " "$68,706,298"           "$56,837,104"          
#>  [4] "$48,767,052"           "$21,608,891"           "$14,331,687"          
#>  [7] "$8,775,344"            "$6,427,816"            "$9,803,091"           
#> [10] "$5,111,098"            "$3,983,009"            "$5,638,656"           
#> [13] "$3,081,926"            "$2,526,561"            "$1,850,628"           
#> [16] "$813,849"              "$534,351"              "$743,090"             
#> [19] "$421,474"              "$790,248"              "$640,753"             
#> [22] "$616,057"              "$550,994"              "$336,339"             
#> [25] "$220,670"              "$85,574"               "$31,368"              
#> [28] "$16,475"               "$5,343"                "$6,351"               
#> [31] "$910,502"              "$131,938"              "$135,891"             
#> 
#> $`Superman Returns`
#>  [1] "Weekend\n            " "$52,535,096"           "$76,033,267"          
#>  [4] "$21,815,243"           "$12,288,317"           "$7,375,213"           
#>  [7] "$3,788,228"            "$2,158,227"            "$1,242,461"           
#> [10] "$848,255"              "$780,405"              "$874,141"             
#> [13] "$1,115,228"            "$453,273"              "$386,424"             
#> [16] "$301,373"              "$403,377"              "$296,502"             
#> [19] "$331,938"              "$216,430"              "$173,300"             
#> [22] "$40,505"              
#> 
#> $`Avengers : Endgame`
#>  [1] "Weekend\n            " "$357,115,007"          "$147,383,211"         
#>  [4] "$63,299,904"           "$29,973,505"           "$17,200,742"          
#>  [7] "$22,063,855"           "$8,037,491"            "$4,870,963"           
#> [10] "$3,725,855"            "$1,987,849"            "$6,108,736"           
#> [13] "$3,118,317"            "$2,104,276"            "$1,514,741"           
#> [16] "$952,609"              "$383,158"              "$209,992"             
#> [19] "$100,749"              "$50,268"               "$70,775"              
#> [22] "$86,837"               "$12,680"              
#> 
#> $`Man of Steel`
#>  [1] "Weekend\n            " "$116,619,362"          "$41,287,206"          
#>  [4] "$20,737,490"           "$11,414,297"           "$4,719,084"           
#>  [7] "$1,819,387"            "$749,233"              "$466,574"             
#> [10] "$750,307"              "$512,308"              "$353,846"             
#> [13] "$290,194"              "$390,175"              "$120,814"             
#> [16] "$61,017"
```

If you have 5000 movies to look up, it is going to take a *long* time to send and parse all these requests. Depending on your internet connection, it may well take 2-3 seconds per movie. That's not bad, but it may still be 4 hours of processing time. I would recommend starting with an empty list and writing each result to the list as it is received, so that if something breaks after an hour or two, you don't lose everything you have so far.

Comment: With all due respect Allan, but even i can add the links manually and perform the task. but what if i have got 5000 movie names and i have to fetch the weekend collections, then i wont add the url's manually...that's why i am looking for an appropriate solution.

Comment: @ShashankMeshram Sorry - you never mentioned this in your question. You said you had 5.

Comment: yeah @Allan, i do agree with you that i didn't mention that i had a list of 5000 movies,  but the idea from the start was how do i get the required details at once without fetching the url's of the movies manually....and i am sorry for the confusion..but thanks for your valuable answer and feedback.. it helped me learn something new...and now i have edited my question for a better understanding...any help from your side will be appreciated..

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer @AllanCameron. I still wish to ask you, is there any way where we don't have to add the names of the movies manually in the code. because adding 5ooo movie names to code manually will be a huge task. i have got the names of these movies in excel sheet. is there a way to just fetch the names of the movies from the excel sheet and get the work done ??

Comment: Yes @ShashankMeshram. There are lots of easy ways to do this. For example, you could just copy them to the Clipboard in Excel then go to R and do `movies <- readClipboard()`